# Sync tables with selections

Tags: mysql, innodb, php

I have a problem that I don't know how I could solve it.

I have two tables in two different databases on two servers.

Server 1 (Master) has the data and server 2 is the slave.
But Server 2 only needs 3 col's of 30 col+ table

And I sync insert, update and delete from the Master to the slave.

What I could do is a Cronjob, using the php application or maybe has MySQL/InnoDB a way todo it?

Best regards :)

Answer (score 0):

On the Replica, you could either of

- Provide a `VIEW` that exposes only the 3 columns.
- Use `GRANT` to limit what users can see or do with each column.

Another approach is to *vertically* split the table:

- `t3` has the 3 columns; it is replicated
- `t27` has the other 27 columns; it is not replicated
- `t30` is a `VIEW` composed of a `JOIN` of the other two tables based on their shared `PRIMARY KEY`.  This could satisfy most of the existing activity on the Primary server.